# Tkinter Python Remove Vertical Spaces

Tags: python, user-interface, text, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

buttonOK = tk.Button(root, text='B1')
MCC = tk.Button(root, text='B2')
TID = tk.Button(root, text='B3')
CURRENCY = tk.Button(root, text='B4')
COUNTRY = tk.Button(root, text='B5')
RESPONSE = tk.Button(root, text='B6')


B1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
B2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
B3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
B4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
B5.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
B6.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

label1 = tk.Entry(root, bd =8)
label1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

label=tk.Text(root,background="yellow")
label.insert(index=0.0, chars="Enter values below\nand click search.\n") 
label.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to build a GUI in Python using Tkinter but the space for the inserted text label as "Enter values below\nand click search.\n" occupies about 6 blank rows. Please help me remove it. My current result using the code above is the left one, I want to have the right one image.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use `sticky=tk.E+tk.W`, you can just use `sticky="EW"`.

Comment: btw you are trying to set `B1`-`B6` to a grid but you have not defined any widgets with those names. I am assuming you are trying to apply the grid manager to your buttons previously listed in your code. If so you need to correct your grid assignments.

Answer (score 4):

When you create the text widget, specify the number of lines you want it to display, for example:

`label=tk.Text(root,background="yellow", height=3)`

Failing to specify means it will default to 24, hence why it is so large in your program.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Thought default is always set to 1.

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as accepted if you have no further need for help on this topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the `grid()` mistake in your code.

You could correct the sizing issue by providing a weight and starting geometry size.

UPDATE:

If you provide weights to the proper rows and columns give your Text widget a default height of say 3 and tell the `grid()` on your Text widget to `sticky="nsew"` you can have your program start out the size you want and be able to resize evenly if you want to.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# we want all 3 columns to resize evenly for the buttons so we provide
# a weight of 1 to each. We also want the first row where the text box is
# to resize so there is not unwanted behavior when resizing, so we set its weight to 1.
# keep in mind a weight of zero (default) will tell tkinter to not resize that row or column.
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

buttonOK = tk.Button(root, text='B1')
MCC = tk.Button(root, text='B2')
TID = tk.Button(root, text='B3')
CURRENCY = tk.Button(root, text='B4')
COUNTRY = tk.Button(root, text='B5')
RESPONSE = tk.Button(root, text='B6')
# corrected the variables being assigned a grid location
buttonOK.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
MCC.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
TID.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
CURRENCY.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
COUNTRY.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
RESPONSE.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

label1 = tk.Entry(root, bd =8)
label1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
# added a height of 3 to the Text widget. to reduce its starting height
label=tk.Text(root,background="yellow", height=3)
label.insert(index=0.0, chars="Enter values below\nand click search.\n") 
# added stick="nsew" so the text box will resize with the available space in the window.
label.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you're guessing how tall the window should be. If this code runs on a system with different resolution or different fonts, the size may not be appropriate.

Comment: @BryanOakley I could probably rewrite it to measure the starting window size and set my minimum/maximum width to that size. Without knowing more about the need for a specific height I think this was a good start for the OP. I will review my answer when I get a min off of my current project.

Comment: Yes, you could. That's way more trouble than it's worth, when all that really needs to be done is to set the height of the text widget to three lines, and let tkinter do all of the calculations for you.

Comment: @BryanOakley I probably should have put a weight on the columns as well so that resizing would not be a visual problem. That would remove the need to max/min size.

Comment: yes, if you use grid you should always give a positive weight to at least one row and one column.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated my answer. I still want to include weights as I think the window would look odd if someone resizes it without weights. Mostly because the OP did not show in their code that that wanted the size to not be resizable so I assumed it may be resized at some point.